# HTTP Post with Volley--- XML post, JSON Response

Tags: android, json, xml, post, android-volley

I'm trying to make an API call, and the API expects `XML` of the format:

```
 <root>
<subject>Security</subject>
<request>GetSessionInfo</request>
<sessionGUID>999999999999</sessionGUID>
<userGUID></userGUID>
<emptyString/>
<lastUpdateDate>
<forceLoad>0</forceLoad>
<transporterFormat>2</transporterFormat>
<parms>            {
                            "sessionGUID":"99999999999999"
            }
            </parms>
</root>
```

But it's sending me the output in `JSON`. I've been trying to accomplish this using `Volley`:

```
        RequestQueue mRequestQueue = RequestQueueSingleton
           .getInstance(this.getApplicationContext())
           .getRequestQueue();

        String targetURL = "http://api.myurl.com";

        StringRequest postRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, targetURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        userGUID = response;


                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> parms = new HashMap< >();
                JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonRequest.put("sessionGUID", sessionGUID);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                parms.put("requestData",
                        getXML(SECURITY, GET_SESSION_INFO, "", sessionGUID, "", null, jsonRequest));
                return parms;
            }
        };
        postRequest.setTag("POST");
        System.out.println("we've attempted to use Volley");
        mRequestQueue.add(postRequest);


With the reference GetXML methods as follows: 

     public String getXML(String subject, String request, String userGUID, String sessionGUID,, Date lastUpdateDate, JSONObject parms) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String date;
        if (lastUpdateDate == null) date = "";
        else date = lastUpdateDate.toString();
        stringBuilder.append("<root>\n <subject>" + subject + "</subject>\n")
        .append("<request>" + request + "</request>\n ")
                .append("<sessionGUID>" + sessionGUID + "</sessionGUID>\n")
                .append("<userGUID>" + userGUID + "</userGUID>\n")
                .append("<emptyString>" + "" + "</emptyString>\n ")
                .append("<lastUpdateDate>" + date + "</lastUpdateDate>\n ")
                .append("<forceLoad>0</forceLoad>\n" + " <transporterFormat>2</transporterFormat>\n")
                .append("<parms>" + parms.toString() + "</parms>\n" + "</root>");

        String result = stringBuilder.toString();
        System.out.println(result);
        return result;
    }
```

I'm not sure if there's an issue with my use of `Volley` or if the library doesn't support the action that I'm attempting entirely. I think that I may need to implement a custom request type that sends an `XML` string and returns a `JSON` object, but the relative lack of documentation makes me unsure how to do that. Any help would be appreciated, sorry for the length!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way in volley by which we can send custom body. This is done by overriding getBody(). You don't need to override getParams(). Instead replace your getParams() function with below code snippet.

```
 @Override
    public byte[] getBody() throws AuthFailureError {
               JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
                try {
                    jsonRequest.put("sessionGUID", sessionGUID);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        String body = getXML(SECURITY, GET_SESSION_INFO, "", sessionGUID, "",  null, jsonRequest));
        return body.getBytes();
    }
```